# w3 total cache uninstall remove cache

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm experiencing a hug problem on a wordpress website.

I have to migrate this website to new hosting provider; actually old developer used to install 'n setup w3 total cache plugin that I'd like to remove from.

I deactivated cache from w3 total cache configuration, then I deactivated and deleted the plugin. Moreover, I deleted every occurence of *cache directories under wp-content/ tree.
Then, I deleted .htaccess and generate it again from wordpress backend. 
At the end, I deleted old theme then I started to use the default one (twentyfourteen).

Even if I can see the single post correctly, frontpage is still cached. What about it?

Comment: Sure it's not just your browser or some intermediary proxy?

Answer (score 0):

try edit wp-config.php and see if there is any WP_CACHE defined , if so remove .
you may also see caching setup file link , if so you should remove that too .

now open your site and please hard reload your page by pressing control + f5 (on windows )  or shift + refresh button on mac .